# ADB and Android App communication mode

Tags: android, python, shell, adb

I'm working on an app which has timed control from adb console. The 'adb shell sendevent' command controls the touch event of the app. But this touch event is timed and the commnd

```
import os


apkLocation = "/Users/siddharthan64/Desktop/adt/sdk/platform-tools/"
os.chdir(apkLocation)

cmdList = ['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 53 251','./adb shell sendevent /       dev/input/event2: 3 54 399','./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 48 10','./adb shell  sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 50 7','./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 0 2 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 50 7']
cmdList.append[,'./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 0 2 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 0 0 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 57 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 53 251']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 54 399']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 48 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 3 50 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 0 2 0']
cmdList.append['./adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2: 0 0 0']
for tcmd in cmdList:
p = os.popen(tcmd,"r")
```

is sent when a certain event happens on the app.

Comment: there's no colon `:` in the device name. Also read this http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2013/06/emulating-touchscreen-interaction-with.html

Answer (score 2):

Actually the `sendevent` differs from device to device. This is from my personal experience. If you are trying to simulate touch events, then you can use the concept of `Instrumentation` in Android.

So, you need to have a `BroadcastReceiver` that receives input touch co-ordinates from the `adb` shell.

Below is the code for `BroadcastReceiver` which has the instrumentation code:

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent i) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Toast.makeText(arg0, "Broadcast intent received...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String args=i.getStringExtra("vals");
        String[] arr=args.split(" ");
        final int myVal1=Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        final int myVal2=Integer.parseInt(arr[1]);
        //Toast.makeText(arg0, "vals:"+args, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Toast.makeText(arg0, "myVal1="+myVal1+"\nmyVal2="+myVal2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Thread myThread=new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                Instrumentation myInst = new Instrumentation();
                myInst.sendKeyDownUpSync( KeyEvent.KEYCODE_B );

                myInst.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,myVal1, myVal2, 0));

                myInst.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),MotionEvent.ACTION_UP,myVal1, myVal2, 0));
            };
        };
        myThread.start();
    }
```

You need to register your `BroadcastReceiver` in you `manifest` as shown below:

```
<receiver android:name="MyReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Once your app is up, connect your device in debug mode, in the command prompt, put the following command:

```
adb shell am broadcast --es vals "10 20" -n com.pkgName.appName/com.pkgName.appName.MyReceiver
```

The above command will trigger the `BroadcstReceiver` of your application, and a touch will be simulated at co-ordinates (10,20). You can replace it with the values you want.

**Note:** If the app is minimized, and you are trying to simulate the touch events, the app will force close, as the android developers have restricted this future, as it can be easily misused by hackers.

Comment: Hello zac thank you for the answer.What if i need to time the commands from the adb console? the broadcast receiver receives the information that action is done and so the next set of actions is ready to follow.

Comment: For timing you need to write a python script accordingly.. Give some delay and execute the command as required with the required coordinates.